# How to use curl to sent a request to Wso2 instead of ant

Tags: wso2-esb

I am still very very new to ESB and my first start is WSO2. I am going through the tutorial on the site and i am able to set it up correctly. Now my question is how can i use curl to make a request to the ESB server rather than Apache ant.

The request i want to send is written in ant as bellow which currently works fine.

```
ant stockquoat -Dtrpurl=http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoatProxy -Dmode=quoat -Dsymbol=IBM
```

from my experience i know that the -D option is for passing parameters.

So how do i pass this in curl

Answer (score 0):

curl command

```
curl --header "Content-Type: text/xml;charset=UTF-8" --header "SOAPAction:urn:getQuote" --data @request.xml http://localhost:8280/services/StockQuoatProxy
```

request.xml file should contain this payload

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"><wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:aff28543-56ba-4aef-982a-f74a685d777d</wsa:MessageID><wsa:Action>urn:getQuote</wsa:Action></soapenv:Header><soapenv:Body><m0:getQuote xmlns:m0="http://services.samples"><m0:request><m0:symbol>IBM</m0:symbol></m0:request></m0:getQuote></soapenv:Body></soapenv:Envelope>
```